# add target="_blank" to certain links that don't already have target specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, coldfusion

I realize there are thousands of similar questions already asked, but after spending 30 minutes browsing, I wasn't able to find one that addresses my specific situation.

I'm looking for a ColdFusion 7/8 or Javascript or JQuery solution. CF preferable.

I need a script that will search a large text string to find all case-insensitive instances of...
`<a href="http://[something_external]">`
That DO NOT already have a target specified. And replace them with...
    `<a href="http://[something_external]" target="_blank">`

So, the criteria for a link that will be altered are:

1. href value starts with "http://"
2. href value does not contain "ourdomain.com"
3. no target value already specified

For instance, I found the following online, but it isn't quite right:
`REReplaceNoCase(mystring, '(<a href="http://[^"]+")>', '\1 target="_blank">', 'ALL')`

Make sense? Doable?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? I wasn't able to test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $.each($('a[href^=http]'), function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('href').indexOf('ourdomain.com') >= 0 || typeof($this.attr('target')) != "undefined" || $this.attr('target', '_blank');
  });
});
```

- Loop through all links beginning with `http` when the document is
  ready
- Contains `ourdomain.com`?
- Has attribute `target`?
- Set attribute `target`

Comment: should it be =0 and ="undefined"?

Comment: No, `indexOf` returns the position of where that string is found OR -1, and `==` is a comparison operator vs `=` which is an assignment operator

Comment: Also, you want it to return false if there is to `target` found, so it passes by in the `||/OR` statement and assigns the `target` property

Comment: But the criteria are that the link does NOT contain "ourdomain.com" and that it does NOT already have a target defined.

Comment: Right, so if it does contain "ourdomain.com", it will return `true` and exit the `OR` statmement. If it doesn't, `false` tells the parser to continue through and execute the OR statement

Comment: One last question... Can we also set it to ignore links beginning with "/"? Those would also be links to ourdomain.com although the ourdomain.com isn't explicitly specified.